# Java memory allocation for member function

Tags: java, memory

Does compiler allocated different memory area for public member function and private member function or they are allocated in same memory area?  And Where exactly they are allocated(i.e heap,stack...)?

I mean to say that OOP concept Like misusing of member function is limited only while writing the code and afterwards...i mean after compiling to bytecode there is no differ as such in memory representation ,,Correct me if i am wrong somewhere..

Comment: This is a strange question. What are you *really* trying to understand?

Comment: From the standpoint of how it's stored, there is no difference between a public function and a private one.

Comment: There's no difference. Instance variables & the objects they are pointing to are stored in the heap.

Comment: The only difference is that there a modifier for access of the method which is set to private for private and public for public.  Otherwise there is no difference at all.  Private methods still need to be accessed by the same class.

Answer (score 0):

- Member functions in Java are stored in the Stack
- Instance variables, objects are stored in the Heap
- Local variables are stored in the Stack

Comment: -1: The part about functions being stored on the stack is nonsense; what does that even mean?

Answer (score 0):

The classes/methods or any other `meta-data` is stored by the JVM in an area which is called: [*Non-Heap Memory*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html)

Objects, including instance/class-member variables are stored during run time on the heap.

The confusion in the two other answers rises because the method-members are stored in the stack when the function is running in a frame which is destroyed once the method is done.

Comment: Method area is part of heap area..The method area is logically part of the heap but a Java virtual machine implementation may choose not to either garbage collect or compact it.